# how to disable print and download option in mozilla

Tags: php, html, firefox, iframe, mozilla

**    i have triend this but its working in chrome but not working in mozilla**please help me on this

> also if there is any better way to disable this please let me know

```
 <iframe id="iframepdf" ALLOWTRANSPARENCY="true" src="<?php echo $_SESSION[$tmp_id].'#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&statusbar=0&notoolbar=1&view=Fit;readonly=true; disableprint=true;'?>" style="width:100%;height:100%;border: 10px solid white;border-radius: 5px;"></iframe>
```